# Combinatorial Proof of Cycles from n elements

Tags: combinatorics

How do I prove $$c(n,n-3) = nC2 \cdot  nC4$$ where $c(n,n-3)$ is the number of ways to partition $[n]$ into $n-3$ cycles? $nCk$ is the number of ways to select $k$ unordered elements from $[n]$

I tried considering the number of singletons in the partition.
There are $n-4$ singletons and a 4-cycle, $n-5$ singletons and a 2-cycle and a 3-cycle, or $n-6$ singletons and $3$ 2-cycles.

However, I am getting $$3!\cdot  nC4 + 2!\cdot  nC5\cdot  5C2 + nC6 \cdot  6C2 \cdot  4C2,$$ respectively, which is not giving the desired result. Is one of these expressions wrong?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You have a mistake; instead of ${}_nC_6\times {}_6C_2\times  {}_4C_2$, it should be $\frac1{3!}({}_nC_6\times  {}_6C_2\times  {}_4C_2)$, because the order of the two-cycles does not matter. Otherwise, your answer is correct. All that remains is to prove that ${}_nC_2\times {}_nC_4$ is equivalent to your formula.